# Nuxt middleware keep redirecting to login page eventhough authenticated

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxtjs

I'm using nuxtjs, vuex and vuex-persist plugin. I've added the middleware to all the pages. It works fine but whenever i refresh the page, the auth.js middleware keeps redirecting to the login page eventhough the user is authenticated (true).

**Auth.js middleware**

```
export default function({store, redirect}){
    if (store.state.isLogin == false) {
        return redirect('/login')
    }
}
```

**Store.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
    isLogin: false,
})

export const mutations = {
    setLogin(state) {
        state.isLogin = true
    },
    removeLogin(state){
        state.isLogin = false
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you implementing vuex-persist in your store?

Comment: @sebasaenz i followed this tutorial https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/getting-started-nuxt/ and i already check the data is persist in localstorage. In vuex also the data is not gone when refresh

Comment: you can try out the solution in this issue https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist/issues/119